# Using projection to find the distance between a vector and a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I'm doing pretty basic linear algebra practice right now and came across this problem:

> Find the distance from the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ to the plane $x_1 + x_3 = 0$.

**My initial attempt:**

I found the normal vector of the plane, which is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. I then tried finding the projection of the original vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ onto the normal vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, so I got $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

I then subtracted the original vector from this projection onto the plane and got $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

So, I found the length of the vector $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ which is $\sqrt{6}$.

But, this wasn't the right answer, and I'm not sure why my method doesn't work. Shouldn't the length of an orthogonal projection of a vector onto a plane be the distance between the vector and the plane? I don't believe I made any simple algebraic mistakes either. Using this formula:

> The distance from $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ to the plane $Ax + By + Cz + D = 0$ is
> $$ \text{Distance} = \frac{|Ax_0 + By_0 + Cz_0 + D|}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 
> + C^2}}$$

I got $2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Since you're already familiar with LaTeX, you can use it on this site by using the dollar sign character, $, around the latex equations. Once the edit goes through (if it does), please transcribe your images

Comment: ok! i'll try that right now

Comment: I'm not fully sure how, but you ended up with the projected point and the vector between the real and projected points mixed up

Answer (score 1):

All of your computations are correct, the issue is mostly conceptual.

Let $V$ denote the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ given by the plane $x_1 + x_3 = 0.$ Then the projection of $(1,2,3)$ onto this plane is $\operatorname{proj}_V(1,2,3) = (-1,2,1),$ as you calculated. Note that this projection vector is *in the plane* $x_1 + x_3 = 0$ (the first component plus the third component is zero).

You also found that $(1,2,3) = \operatorname{proj}_V(1,2,3) + (2,0,2).$ So $(2,0,2)$ is the vector going from $\operatorname{proj}_V(1,2,3)$ to the point $(1,2,3)$ and so the length of this vector will be the distance from the point to the plane. Draw a picture to see this a bit more clearly!

Comment: Oh, I understand! So, the length of the projection of <1, 2, 3> onto <1, 0, 1> is what I want.

Comment: Yeah, that's right